# Software license for freelance developer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, licensing

I have recently entered the world of freelancing/contracting as a .NET software developer.

I would like to have ONE Visual Studio 2012 Developer and ONE SQL Server 2008 Developer license, so that I may test out the new features and practice development in my own time to keep my skills up to date.  I do not want to develop any software to sell etc. it is purely for self educational purposes.

I understand that the express additions of the software are free, but since they do not support the installing of plugins (eg nUnit), they are not be suitable to my needs.

Please can you help me identify if such a license exists (for a developer practicing development and not planning to distribute any software) and where I can find information on costing and purchasing?

Thanks

Comment: If you can live with SQL Server 2012, [it can easily be bought straight from Microsoft](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/SQL-Server-Developer-Edition-2012/productID.281182300).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming itself. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question here, seems you can get it on the online store at the location below:

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msuk/en_GB/pdp/Visual-Studio-Professional-2013/productID.288656800

Comment: This is great, just what I was looking for. You're a really cool guy caa.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Microsoft DreamSpark Program for students, you can join & get all the software needed.

[DreamSpark for Students](https://www.dreamspark.com/)

Comment: Yes this is true, however, is this for freelancers/contractors also??

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit long after the post, but I have found this at the top of searching for an answer to this question and have also discovered a new solution.

A new license that came out in November 2014 which has solved this for me is Visual studio 2013 Community edition.

I'm downloading it, so can't confirm, but from everything I'm reading, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx, it's Visual studio 2013 professional, with full extensions, for free, for individuals or small teams/companies, to make free or paid for products. You basically can't be an Enterprise company, 250+ employees and huge profit etc.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is probably an [MSDN subscription](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/msdn-subscriptions-vs). *Visual Studio Professional with MSDN* is not that expensive and includes SQL Server.

Another options is [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx), however I am not sure whether freelancers qualify for the program.

Comment: Visual Studio Professional with MSDN - $1,199.00. Too expensive for practicing